# Adding favicon to websites hosted on github pages

Tags: html, github-pages

I'm trying to add favicon to my webpage on github but it does not seem to appear.

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/my_logo.ico?" type="image/x-icon" sizes="16x16">`

I have searched for it online and, implemented those solutions but it does not seem to work

solutions I have tried:

1.added a "?" at the end of href link

2.Moved it from images folder to root folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the path to the icon correct?

For ex., there is

```
<link rel="icon" href="/assets/images/favicon.png">
```

on my blog powered by GitHub. And the favicon image location is

```
github.com/{USER_NAME}/{USER_NAME}.github.io/tree/master/assets/images/favicon.png
```

Comment: Yep.Now it works seems I missed the "/" at the beginning of the href . The path for the href should be changed to match the git repository.